# To prove $\pi(x)>\dfrac x{\ln x} , \forall x \ge 17$ by elementary argument

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there an elementary argument for proving $$\forall x \ge 17:\pi(x)>\dfrac x{\ln x}  $$ ? where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function ....

Comment: I doubt it. If you have the prime number theorem with error bounds, you can get the inequality $\pi(x) > \frac{x}{\ln x}$ for $x\geqslant 17$ (if it's true, didn't check) from that with elementary arguments, probably. But from scratch, I think it's beyond elementary arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that it's "elementary", but according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) e.g. Dusart proves
$$ \pi(x) > \dfrac{x}{\ln x} + \dfrac{x}{\ln(x)^2} \ \text{for} x \ge 599 $$
and then you can check it for each integer $x \in [17, 598]$.